# Red and blue balls lined up

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

On a plane, is it possible to arrange $6$ red points and $6$ blue points such that

1. No $2$ points coincide.
2. For any line containing two or more points, not all the points on that line are of the same color.

One obvious arrangement is of course for all $12$ points to be on the same line. But is there any other non-trivial arrangements? After many trials I believe that this is impossible, but cannot come up with a proof. The difficulty is that there are many possibilities to consider, and I think maybe discussing by cases is not the way to go.

I wonder whether or not this lines-and-points set up can be translated into some other mathematical objects (e.g. graphs) and the result can be proved in a clean way.

[image: red and blue points]

---

### Update

As pointed out by Erick Wong this is a generalization of Sylvester's problem. [This](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02112289) survey mentions T. Motzkin's proof in the section "*colored pointsets and monochromatic linear subsets*" for arbitrary numbers of red and blue points. The proof uses the [duality principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)) of the projective plane which I cut and paste below for those who are familiar with these concepts. I would still appreciate a proof in the original point formulation.

[image: the survey]

Comment: All points on a single line?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "If some points lie on a line, they cannot be of the same color" ? Since for every couple of points, there is a line going through them, as long as you have two points of the same color, you have line between them.

Comment: "If some points lie on a line, they cannot be of the same color".How could this be  since it is always possible to join 2 points on a plane with a line ?

Comment: sorry I meant all points on a line cannot be the same color -- there must be at least one blue point on any line determined by 2 red points, and vice versa.

Comment: @asterix314 That makes this an interesting generalization of [Sylvester's problem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/Sylvester.shtml) (well, if we allow arbitrarily many red and blue points).